# How to find position of <li> in <ul> using jquery and css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a simple navigation bar . I have two UL lists in the navigation bar.  I want to select the li which gets onto the next line.
I want to use jQuery and CSS.

I have added the jsFiddle . please drag the draggable to right side to make the nav bar compressed.

```
<ul class="header">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Facebook Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Twitter Handle</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Search on Wikipedia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Go to Quora.com</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wrump1ps/

Comment: and the question is ?

Comment: *I have two UL lists* There is only one ul list

Comment: There is only one ul in your html - are you trying to create a dropdown? what have you tried?

Comment: By `position of li`, do you mean the position of the li when it it comes down when the viewport width is less?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I gave you all. I will edit the question and will try to explain it better :)

Comment: **anpsmn** . ya .. when the LI moves down due to view port size, i want to apply some theme to it. Can it be possible.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you are asking but looking to the question title, How to know position of your `li's` inside your `ul`, Using jQuery:

```
$('li', 'ul').index(); // Returns the position of the li
$('li', 'ul').eq(0); // Returns the first li element (with index 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to split your single list into two lines at a specificed `<li>` element you can float them and then use `nth-child` and `clear:both;`

http://jsfiddle.net/wrump1ps/1/

```
.header {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
ul.header li:nth-child(4) {
    clear: both;
}
```